# How to display shape files stored in a database into a web page

Tags: python, geodjango, django

I'm pretty new to geodjango and python in general. But I would like to display my shapefiles stored in my database into a web pages and present them in layers and retrieve certain information if a user want to.

Comment: Generally, shapefiles aren't stored *in* databases, they are converted to tables with geometry.  If you mean that you loaded shapefile data into a database (as opposed to a BLOB of a zip file of the 3-12 files that make up a shapefile), you should probably **edit** the question to make that clear.

Comment: shapefiles in postgis (database) can be extracted and reprojected on the fly in GeoJSON which will be more web friendly for web browsers

Answer (score 3):

You need a Javascript library for that. For example [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) or [LeafLeat](http://leafletjs.com/).

I'll show you one way to display data with OL.

First you have to create models in models.py:

```
# Creates point layer in database
class ShapefilePoint(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
  geom = models.PointField()
  objects = models.GeoManager()
```

This is an example for a point layer. Class is your table in database with geodata with attributes (id, name etc.)

Then you have to add a shapefile with the same structure to your database.

Now when youve got your spatial data in db, you can display them in templates.

We need our table from db converted to vector format, that can be displayed by OL.

In views.py:

```
def shpPoint(request):
  points = ShapefilePoint.objects.kml()
  return render_to_kml("placemarks.kml", {'places': points})

# renders map template
def index(request):
  return render_to_response("map.html")
```

First function creates a kml from template. It takes table with data from the database and add objects to this kml. More about that you can find in geodjango documentation, I only paste this template here (placemarks.kml):

```
{% extends "base.kml" %}
{% block placemarks %}{% for place in places %}
  <Placemark>
    <name>{% if place.name %}{{ place.name }}{% else %}{{ place }}{% endif %}</name>
    <description>{% if place.description %}{{ place.description }}{% else %}{{ place }}{% endif %}</description>
    {{ place.kml|safe }}
  </Placemark>{% endfor %}{% endblock %}
```

Now we need to map our .kml in urls.py:

```
...
url(r'^point/', shpPoint),
url(r'^index/', index),
...
```

And your link to the layer is ex: http://localhost:8080/point

So we only need to create html templates with the map canvas. You can get more info about this in OL or Leaflet documentation.

Simple example for OL:

```
<body onload="init()">
    <h2> Simple Geoportal </h2>
    <div id='map'></div>
</body>
```

Our map canvas:

```
var map;


    function init(){
        map = new ol.Map({
            target:'map',
            renderer:'canvas',
            view: new ol.View({
                projection: 'EPSG:3857',
                center: ol.proj.transform([19, 52], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                zoom:6,
            })
        });
        var osm = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });
```

And you can add this point layer from .kml with:

```
var PointLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: 'Point',
    source: new ol.source.KML({
        projection:new ol.proj.get("EPSG:3857"),
    url:'http://localhost:8000/point/',
    extractStyles: false
    }),
  style: (function() {
  var textStroke = new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'yellow',
    width: 3
  });
  var textFill = new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'black'
  });
  return function(feature, resolution) {
    return [new ol.style.Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'yellow'}),
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red'})
    }),
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '11px arial,sans-serif',
        text: feature.get('name'),
        fill: textFill,
        stroke: textStroke,
        offsetX: 25,
        offsetY: -10
      })
    })];
  };
})()

});
map.addLayer(PointLayer);
```

And thats all. I've written a simple application like that but now it's a little bit out of date, so if you don't understand something, simply check in geodjango and OL documentations. There is also a good book by Eric Westra about programming in python with a geoportal example.

**Edit:** Ok, here is my application, it was fine maybe with django 1.7, I don't remember, but main idea is allways the same: https://bitbucket.org/dmh126/simple-geoportal/overview

Comment: I'm not familiar with the approach you took so I can't confidently upvote, however I definitely agree [the Westra book](http://www.amazon.com/Python-Geospatial-Development-Second-Edition/dp/178216152X) is in line with the OP's interests.